# Is using AVX2 can implement a faster processing of LZCNT on a word array?

Tags: x86, simd, avx, micro-optimization, avx2

I need to bit scan reverse with LZCNT an array of words: 16 bits.

The throughput of LZCNT is 1 execution per clock on an Intel latest generation processors. The throughput on an AMD Ryzen seems to be 4.

I am trying to find an algorithm using the AVX2 instruction set to be faster.

I know AVX-512 has [VPLZCNTD](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vplzcntd:vplzcntq) for 32-bit elements, so if I had AVX512CD I could unpack and use that.

With just the AVX2 instruction set, it is possible to code an algorithm faster than using the x86 asm LZCNT instruction?

Comment: Do you need an array of results, one per element?  Or are you doing one scan over a large array to find the highest set bit in the whole array?  If the latter, yes use AVX2 `vpcmpeqb` to simply search for a non-zero byte, then bitscan it.

Comment: What do you need to do with the result?  Store it?  If so, having the result in a vector is nice even on Ryzen.  4-per-clock lzcnt and 2-per-clock loads don't help if you're limited to 1-per-clock store.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to beat it without AVX512. 1 op per clock is 16 clocks per AVX structure on amounts for intel and 64 ops on AMD. The smallest algorithms I know for this type of thing require lookup tables and or far more operations and branching, so you'd lose out moving to AVX without a dedicated instruction.

Comment: You might be able to build something branchless out of `vpcmpgtb` to check if any bits above the low 4 are set, then the low 2, then the low 1.  Hmm no, you need to be able to produce a unique result for all 8 positions within a byte.  (And then something to combine results from pairs of bytes into words). Even with 16x 16-bit elements per vector, scalar at 1 per clock may still come out ahead. Or maybe even better on Ryzen if you can `shl eax, 16` / `mov ax, cx` to merge 2x 16-bit results into a 32-bit result to store both at once.  No CPUs with AVX2 rename AX separately from RAX so no stalls

Comment: @user2927848: You can use `vpshufb` as a 4-bit LUT after unpacking, then use `pmaxub` to merge results from high/low halves of each byte.

Comment: Hmm, might have to be `vpmaxsb` so we can use negative to indicate that there are no zero bit in this nibble.  But yeah, similar to AVX2 `popcnt`, split into nibbles.  Look up how that algorithm works.  Except for this we probably want 2 separate LUTs, and we still have to `vpaddb` for the high bytes of each pair.

Comment: One option could be to convert `uint16 -> int32 -> float` and extract the exponent (which needs to be adjusted, of course). Another problem here is handling the 0 case. If you don't use the result afterwards (in a vectorized way), I doubt that this is worth the effort ...

Comment: I need an array of results, one per element.

Comment: @GuyB And do you just want to store the results, or do more operations on it? Do you want to store as `uint8`, `uint16`, `uint32`? And what shall be the result for `0` (or will `0` not happen as input)?

Comment: I need to store them as an array of uint8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#include <immintrin.h>

__m256i avx2_lzcnt_epi16(__m256i v) {
    const __m256i lut_lo = _mm256_set_epi8(
        4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 16,
        4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 16
    );
    const __m256i lut_hi = _mm256_set_epi8(
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 16,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 16
    );
    const __m256i nibble_mask = _mm256_set1_epi8(0x0F);
    const __m256i byte_offset = _mm256_set1_epi16(0x0008);
    __m256i t;

    t = _mm256_and_si256(nibble_mask, v);
    v = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_srli_epi16(v, 4), nibble_mask);
    t = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lut_lo, t);
    v = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lut_hi, v);
    v = _mm256_min_epu8(v, t);

    t = _mm256_srli_epi16(v, 8);
    v = _mm256_or_si256(v, byte_offset);
    v = _mm256_min_epu8(v, t);

    return v;
}

// 16 - lzcnt_u16(subwords)
__m256i avx2_ms1b_epi16(__m256i v) {
    const __m256i lut_lo = _mm256_set_epi8(
        12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 9, 0,
        12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 9, 0
    );
    const __m256i lut_hi = _mm256_set_epi8(
        16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 15, 15, 15, 15, 14, 14, 13, 0,
        16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 15, 15, 15, 15, 14, 14, 13, 0
    );
    const __m256i nibble_mask = _mm256_set1_epi8(0x0F);
    const __m256i adj = _mm256_set1_epi16(0x1F08);
    __m256i t;

    t = _mm256_and_si256(nibble_mask, v);
    v = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_srli_epi16(v, 4), nibble_mask);
    t = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lut_lo, t);
    v = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lut_hi, v);
    v = _mm256_max_epu8(v, t);

    t = _mm256_srli_epi16(v, 8);
    v = _mm256_sub_epi8(v, adj);
    v = _mm256_max_epi8(v, t);

    return v;
}
```

For results packed into uint8 use `_mm256_packs_epi16()`.
For packed results in the correct order also use `_mm256_permute4x64_epi64()`.

Solution from [r/SIMD](https://old.reddit.com/r/simd/comments/b3k1oa/looking_for_sseavx_bitscan_discussions/ej3i3aq/).
This solution was also described in the comments here.

Comment: +1, this is exactly what I was thinking of in comments on the question.  (With all the fine details worked out like `vpminub` which I had wrong, and the LUT values worked out, which is farther than I got in my head.)  At 9 total vector ALU instructions per input vector, this should run at about one vector of 16x 16-bit results per 3 cycles on Haswell/Skylake.  (With some front-end bandwidth to spare for load/store / loop overhead.)  `vpackswb` + `vpermq` will probably bottleneck it on shuffle throughput, but still be much better than scalar 16-bit `lzcnt`.  Also a win on Ryzen.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution over the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58827596), using conversion-to-float hack. In my tests on Zen4 has slightly better performance and uses less registers.

```cpp
__m256i avx2_bit_width_epu16(__m256i v)
{
    const __m256i mask = _mm256_set1_epi32(0x0000FFFF);
    __m256i t = _mm256_and_si256(mask, v); // even indices
    v = _mm256_srli_epi32(v, 16); // odd indices - this prevents rounding

    t = _mm256_castps_si256(_mm256_cvtepi32_ps(t));
    v = _mm256_castps_si256(_mm256_cvtepi32_ps(v)); // convert an integer to float

    t = _mm256_alignr_epi8(t, t, 2); // put exponents inplace
    v = _mm256_blend_epi16(t, v, 0b10101010); // restore

    v = _mm256_srli_epi16(v, 23 - 16); // shift down the exponent
    v = _mm256_sub_epi16(v, _mm256_set1_epi16(126)); // undo bias
    v = _mm256_max_epi16(v, _mm256_set1_epi16(0)); // clamp negative for 0 to 0

    return v;
}
```

UPD: updated for large values from 1 << 15 on - gives correct 16.

Comment: The `max` at the end can be avoided if you use `subs_epu16` (unsigned-saturating subtract).  That should be faster on Intel, and better throughput but equal latency on Zen 4.  https://godbolt.org/z/8xzz1rE5K .  You can also use `_mm256_bsrli_epi128(t, 2)` instead of `_mm256_alignr_epi8(t,t,2)` - simpler instruction, can run on more ports on Intel Ice Lake and later, and smaller machine-code size (2-byte VEX).  Or 2 shifts that can run in parallel to feed the blend instead of shuffle -> blend -> shift, although in a loop on Intel that might bottleneck on ports 0 / 1 (also `vcvtdq2ps`.)

Comment: My Godbolt link has a test `main` that checks it against `16 - std::countl_zero( (uint16_t)i )` for every `i` from `0 .. 0xFFFF`, for the version with 2 shifts feeding a blend and `vpsubusw` instead of `vpmaxuw`.